# Is it possible to add array of data in child entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I have issue that I hope someone here will be able to help me.For this exercise I`m using aspnetboilerplate framework.

So I create 3 entity and they ALL work good (at least I guess they work good)

Little bit recap of project

One Recepie HAVE one or more Ingredient

Ingrident.cs

```
    public class Ingrident : Entity
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Master Master { get; set; }

    public int? MasterId { get; set; }

    public Recepie Recepie { get; set; }
    public int? RecepieId { get; set; }

}
```

Master.cs

```
    public class Master : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Image { get; set; }
    public string? ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string? FullDescription { get; set; }
    public string? Keywords { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    public List<Ingrident> Ingridents { get; set; }
}
```

Recepie.cs

```
   public class Recepie : Entity
    {
    public string RecepieName { get; set; }

    public Ingrident Ingridents { get; set; } 
    
    }
```

With this database structure I can add Recepie and add only one ingredient when I try to send [] of Ingredient its show me DTO error.

And here is RecepieAppService.cs

```
 public class RecepieAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<IndexIngrident.Entities.Recepie,RecepieDto>
{
    private readonly IRepository<IndexIngrident.Entities.Recepie> _repository;
    private readonly IRepository<IndexIngrident.Entities.Ingrident> _ingRepository;

    public RecepieAppService(IRepository<IndexIngrident.Entities.Recepie> repository, IRepository<IndexIngrident.Entities.Ingrident> ingRepository)
   : base(repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _ingRepository = ingRepository;
    }

    public List<RecepieFullGetDto> GetAllIncluded()
    {
        var result = _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.Ingridents , x => x.Ingridents.Master);
        Debug.WriteLine(result);

        return ObjectMapper.Map<List<RecepieFullGetDto>>(result);
    }


}
```

RecepieDto.cs

```
    [AutoMap(typeof(IndexIngrident.Entities.Recepie))]

public class RecepieDto : EntityDto
{
    public string RecepieName { get; set; }

    public IngridentRecepieDto Ingridents { get; set; }
}




   public class IngridentRecepieDto : EntityDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RecepieId { get; set; }
}
```

Using **AsyncCrudAppService** my CRUD is automatically generated and I`m able to create new Recepie but when I try to do something like this

[image]

I get error
[image]

Comment: RecepieDto has a single IngridentRecepieDto, but you are passing an array of IngridentRecepieDto.  Try declaring Ingridents as an array in your RecepieDto.  That will break the AutoMap, so you would also need to make Ingridents in Recepie an array as well, which will likely require a change at the data source.  Long story short, Yes it is possible (anything is possible).

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the mapping of objects in both directions, [AutoMapTo (typeof (RecepieDto))] and [AutoMapFrom (typeof (Recepie))], and verify that you have the class, inherits AutomapperProfile

Comment: Hello,I try to put this code but it doesn`t work